# plaidml-setup is not recognized on Windows, even after successful installation

Tags: python, keras, plaidml

I followed all the steps as on [the documentation from VertexAI](https://vertexai-plaidml.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/usage/install.html) but after installing plaidml-keras, when I try to run setup, it throws an error.

```
C:\Users\anura>pip install plaidml-keras
Requirement already satisfied: plaidml-keras in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from plaidml-keras) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras==2.2.4 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from plaidml-keras) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: plaidml in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from plaidml-keras) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras==2.2.4->plaidml-keras) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras==2.2.4->plaidml-keras) (1.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras==2.2.4->plaidml-keras) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: keras-applications>=1.0.6 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras==2.2.4->plaidml-keras) (1.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras==2.2.4->plaidml-keras) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from keras==2.2.4->plaidml-keras) (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from plaidml->plaidml-keras) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.1.6 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from plaidml->plaidml-keras) (1.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi->plaidml->plaidml-keras) (2.20)

C:\Users\anura>plaidml-setup
'plaidml-setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Please can someone help me get through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I didn't find a solution to the original problem, even after multiple reinstalls. Finally, I uninstalled Python, and installed Anaconda3. Installing plaidml through the Anaconda prompt worked. Sadly my GPU is too old to even be recognized. AMD Radeon HD 7870.

But hey, if any future reader of this post has the same issue, try Anaconda prompt. Its highly probable you have it installed anyways. Happy Coding.

Comment: FWIW You probably had a pathing issue... Python knows where to look for python libraries installed by pip, but windows doesn't know where to look for binaries installed by pip. The`PATH` environment variable is a list of directories to check for binaries to execute. Check where the plaidml-setup.exe file lives and add it to the path (or change to that directory before executing the command). In any case, glad you got it working with anaconda... It really is superior for managing multiple deployments.

Comment: I'll take that back. It didn't recognize the GPU by model, but did it by the GPU name 'Pitcairn'. The benchmark clocks at 12.76ms with 19.37ms Inference latency for MobileNet, compared to 536.51ms and 539.13 respectively on my equally old CPU FX8350. So, although I'm not going to break any records, there's a definite win I'd say.

Comment: Also it wasn't a path issue. I checked, but its an old thing now. Glad that its working now.